# Xcode - How to call method from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

**my first class .h :**

```
@interface CollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController <..>

  @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;

  -(void)refreshView;

@end
```

**my first class .m**

```
@implementation CollectionViewController

  -(void)refreshView
  {
      [self.collectionView reloadData];
  }

@end
```

**i need to call this method from my second class**

**my second class .h**

```
@interface CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

   - (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender;

@end
```

**my second class .m**

```
@implementation CollectionViewCell

  - (IBAction)myButtonAction:(id)sender {

  //i need to call the method "refreshView" here

  }

@end
```

I tried to edit the method `refreshView` from private to public but it's not compatible with "`[self.collectionView reloadData];`"

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why this way? You create instances of `UICollectionViewCell` inside `UICollectionViewController` and to reload data on cell which has been selected you call methods from `UICollectionViewDelegate` which you implement as those are only headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to have your cell "know about" its collection view.

Use delegation instead...

### CollectionViewCell.h

```
@protocol CollectionViewCellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)refreshButtonPressedForCell:(CollectionViewCell *)cell;
@end

@interface CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<CollectionViewCellDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

### CollectionViewController.m

```
@interface CollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController <CollectionViewCellDelegate>
@end

@implementation CollectionViewController

- (void)refreshButtonPressedForCell:(CollectionViewCell *)cell {
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

@end
```

Don't forget to set the delegate property on each of your cells!